# ListView: Selected Items Should be Highlighted

Tags: android, android-widget

I've a fairly simple program that implements a ListView.  When I select an item in the list, it briefly turns Orange, then reverts to Black.  However, I would like it to stay Orange after I select the item (until either I clear the item, or select a different item).  I tried to code this but failed.  I think it must be close to correct.  Can anyone tell what I need to modify in the following code to make it work?

file: ./res/layout/main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"              android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"        android:gravity="center">
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"           android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

File: ./res/drawable/list_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"         android:drawable="@color/orange" />
    <item android:state_selected="false"        android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
</selector>
```

File: ./res/values/colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>    <color name="orange">#b0e0e6</color> </resources>
```

File: ./src/com/commonsware/android/linearpct/LinearLayoutDemo.java

```
public class LinearLayoutDemo extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
    private static final String[] items={"1", "2", "4", "8", "16", "32", "64", "128", "256", "512", "1024", "2048", "4096", "8192"};
    ListView myLV;
    ArrayAdapter myAdapter;

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.d("LinearLayoutDemo:", "********: onCreate() begin");
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
        myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        myLV = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        myLV.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        myLV.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }

    @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long lng) {
        view.setSelected(true);
        String selectedFromList =(String) (myLV.getItemAtPosition(position));
        Log.d("LinearLayoutDemo:", "********: OnItemClick: " + selectedFromList);
    }

    @Override public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(parent, view, position, id);
        view.setSelected(true);
        String selectedFromList =(String) (myLV.getItemAtPosition(position));
        Log.d("LinearLayoutDemo:", "********: OnItemClick: " + selectedFromList);
    }
}
```

NOTE: When I run this code, the log messages from onListItemClick() never show in the logs.  So something is wrong there.

Also, I could not figure out how to call super.onItemClick() in onItemClick().  That might be a clue.

Answer (score 2):

in list_selector.xml:

```
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/orange" />
```

called when the object is focused with a D-PAD (track-pad)

```
<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/orange" />
```

called when the object is selected in contextual action bar. (only API 11+)

in API 11- the best way to implementation multi select is Customizing Adapter, to change View bakground color.

```
    class CPGAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Pack> {
public void UpdateItem() {
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    View mView = v;
    if (mView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mView = vi.inflate(R.layout.cpga_xml, null);
    } // inflate
    TextView text = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_cpgatitle);
    // get views from ids
    if (mView != null) {
        if (getItem(position).Selected) {
            mView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.pressed);
        } else {
            mView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.default);
        }
        text.setText(getItem(position).Name);

    }
    return mView;
}

    }
```

and in your code when View is selected:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> AV, View v, int POS, long Id) {
                ((Pack) AV.getItemAtPosition(POS)).Selected = true;
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.pressed);
                                    // or (CPGAdapter(AV.getAdapter)).UpdateItem()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `simple_list_item_1` to `simple_list_item_activated_1`. The color are pretty ugly, if you want nice color you have to extend ArrayAdapter.

```
public class LinearLayoutDemo extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
    private static final String[] items={"1", "2", "4", "8", "16", "32", "64", "128", "256", "512", "1024", "2048", "4096", "8192"};
    ListView myLV;
    ArrayAdapter myAdapter;

@Override public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.d("LinearLayoutDemo:", "********: onCreate() begin");

    myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, items);
    myLV = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    myLV.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    myLV.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    myLV.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long lng) {

    String selectedFromList =(String) (myLV.getItemAtPosition(position));
    Log.d("LinearLayoutDemo:", "********: OnItemClick: " + selectedFromList);
}


}
```

Your can remove the `list_selector.xml` and change your layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"              android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"        android:gravity="center">
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"           android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this later.  I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Why do people post answers that don't work?  Do they work for them?

Comment: What do you mean don't work I ran the code above on ICS and it is fine

Comment: Okay.  I was wondering if it worked for you.  Anyway, it doesn't work for me.  What I mean by that is that when I select an item from the list, the item does not stay 'lit'.  It briefly turns orange, but then reverts to black.

Comment: Why don't you make a project out of the code above and run it to see if it works. you only need the above code and the manifest.

Comment: I did that.  I put the above in a java file (and added some import statements) and a res/layout/main.xml file.  When I click items in the list, they don't stay lit.

Comment: What version are you running and what phone? Try it on another phone if you have another. I ran on 3 phones with one JB and two ICS, and I have no problem. The item I touched stay lit, but the color is very dark.

Comment: I have an Azpen tablet (not phone) running an Android version 4.04.  I don't have a phone.

Comment: I have no idea with your Azpen tablet. You should go to Azpen site and hopefully they have a developer forum where you can ask question.

Comment: No it's a cheap product: $80.  Probably no support at all.  I think instead I will put a TextView below my ListView and program it to display the selected item.  That should be the workaround.  Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Instead of that, look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html there are a few other choice you can make for example simple_list_item_single_choice

Comment: I tried this, and it worked.  Sort of.  There's a check mark that shows me when an item is selected, and that's good.  But it introduced another problems.  Some of the strings like "1024" now appear broken up on multiple lines, some of them appear only one character per line.

Comment: I think you should return your tablet, it might be defected.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [State List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html), especially `android:state_activated="true"`